# ActiveMQ: How to get count of prefetched messages on each consumer

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I am using last version of ActiveMQ Artemis.

My use case is pretty simple. The broker sends a lot of messages to consumer - a single queue. I have 2 consumers per queue. Consumers are set to use default prefetch size of messages (1000).

Is there a way to monitor how many messages are pre-fetch and processed from each consumer?

Comment: The answer which is marked as correct is not, in fact, correct as noted in the comment on that answer. Can you clarify why this was accepted as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis exposes the `DeliveringCount` attribute on QueueControl. See the [management doc](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html) for further details.

Comment: It shows count for a whole queue , not per consumer.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to track messages which are "in delivery" on a per-consumer basis.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only way to see how match messages are delivered to specific consumer (prefetched by consumer) that I found was to create and check a heap dump.